# Working of a CMOS inverter

Tags: cmos

I'm new to this concept and parts of it are a little confusing. I understood the part when a 5V signal is applied as input, a channel is formed in the NMOS device, as the positive voltage attracts electrons, thus output is connected to the ground via the NMOS and hence 0 output. But when 0 volts is applies to the gates of both the devices how does the PMOS conduct for the output to be high? Since both are enhancement mode devices a channel does not exist beforehand and is brought about by introduction of a gate voltage. When 0 gate voltage is applied how does a conducting path get formed in the PMOS for the output to connect to VDD?

Comment: Need a schematic...

Comment: I cant add a picture because I just joined and don't have enough rep yet but it is the basic cmos inverter.

Comment: A PMOS device turns on when there is a voltage between the source and the gate that exceeds the threshold voltage. The source is at +VDD and the gate at 0V in the on state.

Comment: If you added a link, someone could have edited it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the gate voltage of the PMOS device is relative to its source terminal, which is connected to the V<sub>DD</sub> supply. So, when the input to the circuit is at 0V, there is a gate bias on that device of –V<sub>DD</sub>; this is what turns it on and pulls the output high.

Answer (score 0):

A high voltage on the gates will cause the nMOSFET to conduct and the pMOSFET not to conduct and a low voltage on the gates causes the reverse. THe complementary arrangement with common drains and gates allows a common gate voltage with respect to ground to determine which one conduct. What happens in between is also very interesting and not shown is a small bulk resistor on the drain of the n type. (eg 10R)

Let me post a schematic for you with a simulator.
Each single stage CMOS inverter is designed to have a voltage gain of 10, a buffered one is 3 stages so the gain is 1000. I took the liberty of showing the VI curve of each device and the input being a sine wave 500mV biased at Vcc/2.  The simulator is [here.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#$+0+5.0E-6+31.41906602856942+50+5.0+50%0Af+224+128+288+128+1+1.5%0Af+224+224+288+224+0+1.5%0Aw+288+144+288+176+0%0Aw+288+176+288+208+0%0Aw+224+128+224+176+0%0Aw+224+176+224+224+0%0AM+288+176+352+176+0+2.5%0AR+288+112+288+64+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Ag+288+240+288+272+0%0Av+144+176+224+176+0+3+50.0+0.5+2.5+0.0+0.5%0Ag+144+176+144+272+0%0Ao+0+64+0+354+5.0+0.0125+0+-1%0Ao+1+64+0+354+5.0+0.0125+0+-1%0Ao+9+64+0+290+4.374501449566024+9.765625E-105+1+-1%0A)
THe MOSFETS have equal and opposite polarity thresholds of 1.5V and conduct 10mA during the accelerated transition period.
[image]

Comment: So if this has to work as a NOT gate, logic 0 should correspond to a voltage less than -1.5V and logic 1 greater than 1.5V?

Comment: No - look at the actual voltages in the simulator.